# Setting Href to a server path

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, path

How do I set Href to a file on a server (example: \myserver\test\a.txt) correctly? When I assign the path to Href, it adds the domain name in front (http://mydomain.com/myserver/test/a.txt) which is not the correct path.

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to access a UNC file path from a link on a web page?

Comment: Yes, my file path is something like "\\myserver\test\a.txt"--if I type that in Run, it will open my file.

Comment: what are the full paths to the file you are retrieving and the page with the link on it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the file:/// URI paradigm.  For example, I can go in my browser to `file:////sharename/c$/` and it works.

Comment: Can you give this as a href link in your webpage?.

Answer (score 1):

You can't download a file from server from your client side. You have to do this on your server side or make sure that the file which you want to give in href is accessible by adding it in your hosted directory.

One of the better way if you dont want to manually move the files on server is to write code on server side to make a copy of that file from any location on that server as specified by you and put it in hosted directory. Once the file is in hosted directory you can create a link and give it to user for download or access.